# postgres COPY FROM STDIN WITH encoding error with UTF8 by using libpq

Tags: utf-8, pg, libpq

I created database by following command:

```
CREATE DATABASE myendb
ENCODING 'UTF-8' 
LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8'
TEMPLATE template0;
```

I tried to insert Cyrillic symbols encoding by UTF8 into a table by following  copy command by calling PQputCopy..() functions and I got following error:

```
COPY  my_table_name(columns list)
FROM STDIN WITH  CSV DELIMITER AS ';' NULL AS  E'' QUOTE '"' failed.


EOF:0 Message:ERROR:  value too long for type character(15)
```

And I tried to add "ENCODING UTF8" into cmd, I got another error:

```
 COPY   my_table_name(columns list) 
 FROM STDIN WITH  CSV DELIMITER AS ';' NULL AS  E'' QUOTE '"'  ENCODING 'UTF8' failed.


EOF:0 Message:ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd0 0xbb in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

I load Cyrillic sentence encoding by UTF8. The database also created with encoding UTF8. Character set also set as UTF8. I use libpq to connect and perform copy commands. Where no any WIN1252...
Also I tried to add 'set client_encoding='utf8'' - it does not help.
I don't know how resolve this...
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 databases in on server. Default database has encoding WIN1252.  Another database has encoding UTF8. I tried to connect to non-default database with UTF8. But libpq connects to default database, despite of that I defined database name on connection string. This happens, because I used empty password. I should use for password parameter empty quoted string like as - password=''

the solution here: [Postgresql PQconnectdb incorrectly connect to another database, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77555995/postgresql-pqconnectdb-incorrectly-connect-to-another-database-why/77557894#77557894)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).